# Minecraft Test If A Chest Contains An Item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've seen a lot of questions for finding specific items in chests using commands using testforblock but how would you test if any block/item has been placed in a chest?

Thanks

Comment: As in, like a remote comparator?

Comment: @MrLemon I'm unsure what a comparator is fully used for. What I want is a command testing for an item in a chest, then a comparator next to that command block to activate another command block.

Comment: A comparator next to a chest (or any container), will output a redstone signal based on how full the chest is. For a chest, every full stack increases the output signal power by 0.44 (15/27). This number is rounded up, so that any single item in a chest produces an output power of 1.

Comment: @MrLemon I guess it is like a remote comparator then. It needs to do the same thing just from further away

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
/testforblock x y z minecraft:chest -1 {Items:[{}]}
```

Note the extra `{}` in the `Items` list. `{Items:[{}]}` checks if the list of item tags contains an item that matches all the tags present in `{}`. Obviously, `{}` does not contain any tags, meaning every item in the game matches this<sup>1</sup>.

You can achieve the opposite behavior using `{Items:[]}`, which will test for an empty list of items.

<sup>1 Technically, everything matches `{}`, including Creepers, but the `Items` tag limits the scope for us.</sup>

Comment: For once, Minecraft commands behave *exactly* like I thought they would.

Comment: Thanks! I needed this to create a mailbox type system on the server. This works perfectly!