# How to /testforblock chest with items and blocks inside

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

It doesn't have to be specific, just items and blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Minecraft Test If A Chest Contains An Item](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232736/minecraft-test-if-a-chest-contains-an-item)

This question is basically answered what I was looking for. It does testfor if items/blocks that are in a chest.

```
/testforblock x y z minecraft:chest -1 {Items:[{}]}
```

> > You can achieve the opposite behavior using {Items:[]}, which will test for an empty list of items.
> >
> > 1 Technically, everything matches {}, including Creepers, but the
> >     Items tag limits the scope for us.
> >
> > answered Aug 21 at 15:57
>
> MrLemon